# Prove that in Hausdorff spaces:

Tags: general-topology

Prove that in Hausdorff spaces:

a) $A$' is always closed, where $A$' is the derivate set of $A$

b)($A$')' $\subset$ $A$'

c) ($\overline{A}$)' = $A$'

Comment: You need to supply your attempts.  Start with the first one.  Perhaps give us the definition of derivative $A'$.  Then say what would be involved in proving it is closed.

Comment: The derivative of A is the set of all x in X such that for every neighborhood of x we have the neighborhood removing the point intersected with A is different from empty

Comment: Next, how would you go about proving $A'$ is closed?  These are things you should to, in order to avoid having your question put on hold.

Comment: Try to see that its complement is open, but I do not know what would be the complement of that set

Comment: B) and c) are just other ways to say that $A'$ is closed, i.e. a). They are always equivalent.

Comment: Ah ok, if I see that c) is equivalent to a), but can you explain to me why b) it is?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** For (c), note that in any topological space $X$, if $C \subseteq X$ is closed in $X$, then $\text{Cl}(C) = \bar{C} = C$

*Note:* I only put $\text{Cl}(C) = \bar{C}$ for notational purposes, some authors tend to use one or the other to denote the closure of a subset of a topological space. Also the definition of $\text{Cl}(C)$ that I am using here is the intersection of all closed sets containing $C$ as a subset. Furthemore this hint takes into account that you know (a) to be true.